# angularjs response data does not show in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have below code i but data not show in console log please help me i am new in angular.. AND how to show data in HTML

```
 this.$http.get(properties.client+'/123')
          .then(response => {
            $scope.clientdata= response.data;

             console.log($scope.clientdata.address);         
          });
```

address array dose not show in console log,i don't know why  RESPONSE BELOW

```
 [{  "_id": "123",
        "__v": 1,
        "history": [],
    "address": {
            "street_address": "adsf",
            "state": "adsf",
            "zip_code": "adsf",
            "phone_number": "asdf",
            "country": "ads",
            "city": "asdf",
            "site_name": "adsf",
            "_id": "123123",
            "geolocation": {
                "coordinates": [],
                "type": "Point"
            },
            "location": {
                "latitude": null,
                "longitude": null
            },
            "id": "5835baaa71a30ca8319b6e36"
        },
        "current_status": "Assigned",
        "time": 0
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clientdata is an array as per the post, try

```
console.log($scope.clientdata[0].address);
```

**HTML**

```
{{clientdata[0].address}}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to get data in HTML ??

Comment: {{clientdata[0].address}}

Comment: just put {{clientdata}}

Comment: <tr  ng-repeat="x in clientdata">            <td>{{clientdata.current_status}}</td>

Comment: @AdeelKhan it should be <tr ng-repeat="x in clientdata"> <td>{{x.current_status}}</t‌​d>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129534/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-adeel-khan).

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of your JSON data, clientdata is an array of objects and as of current, there is only one object in the array. So, in order to access the address property of the object, you will have to access it in this way

$scope.clientdata[0].address

and in **HTML**

{{clientdata[0].address._id}}

and rest of the address object properties in similar fashion.